# How to bulk convert all the file in a file system branch between Unix and Windows line break format?

Tags: text-processing, newlines

Everybody knows :-) that in Windows plain text files lines are terminated with CR+LF, and in Unix&Linux - with LF only. How can I quickly convert all my source code files from one format to another and back?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That depends: if the files are under version control, this could be a rather unpopular history-polluting decision. Git has the option to automagically convert line endings on check-out.

If you do not care and want to quickly convert, there are programs like `fromdos`/`todos` and `dos2unix`/`unix2dos` that do this for you. You can use `find`: `find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec dos2unix '{}' +`.

Comment: This will run `dos2unix` on *all* files, the ones that already have Unix line-breaks (LF),
as well as the ones in need to convert the Windows line-breaks (CRLF) to LF.
This should be fine, I think. But it's worth a comment. :-)

Comment: Also, I prefer to start with `find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec echo dos2unix '{}' \;`
in order to see what files will be affected before going through with the actual conversion.
Of course, you might not want to follow my suggestion if
the number of files affected is *huge*.

Answer (score 13):

There are several dedicated programs, including

- `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` from the [dos2unix](http://freshmeat.net/projects/dos2unix) tools
- `todos` and `fromdos` from the [tofrodos](http://www.thefreecountry.com/tofrodos/index.shtml) tools

Simply pick the tool for the appropriate direction and pass the names of the files to convert on the command line.

---

If you don't have either, but have Linux or Cygwin:

```
sed -i -e 's/\r\+$//' filename             # dos|unix -> unix
sed -i -e 's/\r*$/\r/' filename            # dos|unix -> dos
```

If you have perl:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\r+$//' filename            # dos|unix -> unix
perl -i -pe 's/\r*$/\r/' filename          # dos|unix -> dos
```

With only POSIX tools (including BusyBox), to go from unix to dos, you'll need to pass the CR character literally in the sed command.

```
cr=$(echo | tr '\n' '\r')
sed -e "s/$cr*\$/$cr/" <filename >filename.dos
mv filename.dos filename
```

In the other direction, you can simply delete all CRs:

```
tr -d '\r' <filename >filename.dos
mv filename.dos filename
```

---

You can use wildcards to convert many files in the same directory at once, e.g.

```
sed -i -e 's/\r\+$//' *.txt
```

To convert all files in the current directory and its subdirectories, if your shell is zsh, you can use `**/`, e.g.

```
sed -i -e 's/\r\+$//' **/*.txt
```

You can use `**/` in bash ≥4, but you need to run `shopt -s globstar` first (you can put this line in your `~/.bashrc`). You can use `**/` in ksh93, but you need to run `set -o globstar` first (you can put this line in your `~/.kshrc`.

If you can only use the tools that require a redirection, use a `for` loop.

```
for x in *.txt; do
  tr -d '\r' <"$x" >"$x.dos"
  mv -- "$x.dos" "$x"
done
```

If you don't have `**/` or need more complex matching to select which files to convert, use the `find` command. Here's a Linux/Cygwin example which converts all files under the current directory and its subdirectories recursively, except for files called `.o` and under subdirectories called `bin`.

```
find -name 'bin' -type d -prune -o \
     \! -name '*.o' \
     -exec sed -i -e 's/\r\+$//' {} +
```

Here's a POSIX example. We tell `find` to start a shell that can perform the necessary redirection.

```
find -name 'bin' -type d -prune -o \
     \! -name '*.o' \
     -exec sh -c '
       tr -d '\r' <"$0" >"$0.dos"
       mv -- "$0.dos" "$0"
' {} \;
```

You can make the `find` method slightly faster, at the expense of more complex code, by using a loop in the shell command.

```
find -name 'bin' -type d -prune -o \
     \! -name '*.o' \
     -exec sh -c '
       for x; do
         tr -d '\r' <"$x" >"$x.dos"
         mv -- "$x.dos" "$x"
       done
' _ {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

**winscp** will also auto-convert, if [told so](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/transfer_mode).

If your files reside all in the same directory:

```
DIRECTORY=/your/directory
unix2dos $DIRECTORY/*
```

Comment: WinSCP doesn't seem to autoconvert files in the current directory - it's more about automatically converting files as part of a transfer process. Even vanilla `ftp` did that.

Answer (score 0):

### Changing from *ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators* to *ASCII text*

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Apr 10 2018 21:31:58)

---

All files in current directory

```
for i in *; do vi -c "set fileformat=unix | wq" "${i}"; done
```

---

Specific mask (all filenames in current directory starting with word "file")

```
for i in file*; do vi -c "set fileformat=unix | wq" "${i}"; done
```

---

Another mask (all filenames in current directory that contain the word "file")

```
for i in *file*; do vi -c "set fileformat=unix | wq" "${i}"; done
```

---

To convert files back to CRLF just change fileformat=unix to fileformat=dos:

```
for i in *file*; do vi -c "set fileformat=dos | wq" "${i}"; done
```

*This is the quickest way if using vim to convert fileformat.*

---

### Alternatively sed can also be used to remove all ^M by pressing CTRL+V and then CTRL+M

```
for i in *; do sed -i s/^M// "$i"; done
```

or

```
for i in *; do sed -i s/^M// "${i}"; done
```

#### This will also change all CRLF files in current directory to ASCII text.

Comment: Your `vi` suggestions will only work when `vi` is aliased to `vim` (the `set fileformat` option is not part of standard `vi`)