# what is the best way to convert CRLF to LF and the viceversa for C++ files in my project

Tags: text-processing, conversion, newlines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to bulk convert all the file in a file system branch between Unix and Windows line break format?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22604/how-to-bulk-convert-all-the-file-in-a-file-system-branch-between-unix-and-window)

which is the best tool to convert the CRLF to LF for my project in C++,one of the guideline is to do so before review.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` tools.

Wrap it in a shell script to match all your source files and it should be done.