# shebang line not working with cr-lf

Tags: command-line, newlines, shebang

Why are the shebang parts of the following elementary scripts not working:

```
$ cat hello.sh
#! /bin/sh
echo Hello
$ ./hello.sh
bash: ./hello.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

$ cat hello.py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
print("Hello")
$ ./hello.py
: No such file or directory
```

whereas calling the interpreter manually is working:

```
$ sh hello.sh
Hello
$ python3 hello.py
Hello
```

Answer (score 12):

Your scripts probably have DOS-style CR-LF line endings and not Unix-style LF line endings. The ^M seen in the error message in the first case is an indication that the 0D character was interpreted as part of the script interpreter name and not as part of the line ending (as one might expect it to be). Since there is no executable file on your system with a path that includes the character 0D (^M), the system is not able to invoke the interpreter. When you manually call your interpreter, it is able to handle both kinds of line endings present in the script.

If you convert the scripts to use Unix-style LF line endings, you should see the shebang working. Read on for an illustration.

In the session below, todos and fromdos are [a utility](http://www.thefreecountry.com/tofrodos/index.shtml) (available on Ubuntu as the package `tofrodos`) to convert the line-ending conventions from CR-LF to LF. Any equivalent utility (see [this unix.SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22604/how-to-bulk-convert-all-the-file-in-a-file-system-branch-between-unix-and-window)) would do for the purpose of demonstration.

The following session transcript (executed with your same script files) should clarify the situation:

```
$ fromdos hello.sh
$ ./hello.sh
Hello
$ todos hello.sh
$ ./hello.sh
bash: ./hello.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
$
$ fromdos hello.py
$ ./hello.py
Hello
$ todos hello.py
$ ./hello.py
: No such file or directory
$
```

It [seems](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/w5dYWUDHLvY/6S_bFnouzzMJ) that it is the kernel that reads the shebang line, and apparently the Linux kernel (at least as of the version on my Kubuntu Saucy system) does not recognize the CR as part of the CR-LF line ending convention.

If the shebang of your script doesn't seem to be working (i.e. manually calling the interpreter on the script works but you can't execute the script using its file name even though you have done `chmod +x` on it) then this is a possible reason.

**NOTE:**
Thanks to the others who commented too. I'd also be happy to hear if there are better answers!

Answer (score 1):

Since `^M` is a valid character in file names, you can solve the problem by adding a symlink to the script language executable with `^M` at the end of the link name (which is - actually - a file name). However, neither `^M`, nor `\r` translate to the true native `CR` character in the link name. Use `echo -e` command to get it working:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/tclsh /usr/bin/tclsh$(echo -e '\r')
```

As can be seen, in this case a `tclsh` scripting executable is supposed. Equally well this applies to python etc. Of course the method is not useful with Bash scripts because the rest of the script file would not work with `CRLF` line endings.

Comment: With many thanks to doneal24 (https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21334/doneal24) in a hidden answer, who supplied the symlink idea (but proposing the insertion of ^M).

Comment: See `"$(printf '\r')"` for a portable way to get a CR character. `$'\r'` is pretty common as well.