# How to combine multiple text files and remove duplicates effectively?

Tags: sort, duplicate

I tried many things but most of them just got stuck or didn't remove the duplicates properly. It doesnt matter if the output file is sorted or not

If file1.txt contains

```
a
b
c
d
e
c
d
```

If file2.txt contains

```
c
d
e
a
f
g
g
h
```

output.txt should contain

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply use `sort -u file[12].txt >output.txt`. that sorts the input while removed duplicates.

make sure your files are in Unix type newline format (LF `\n`) instead of Dos/Windows newline format (CRLF `\r\n`); if not [convert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22604/72456) them by `tr -d $'\r' <filename` or `dos2unix filename` command.

Comment: I tried that. I used `sort -u first.txt second.txt third.txt >output.txt` but [this](https://imgur.com/a/HMe4pY0) is what i got. The duplicates didn't get removed