# bash shell script errors with: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have written the script below, but when I run it from the directory where it is (and also the files)

`bash xmlimport-magento2.sh`

I get this error message:

`xmlimport-magento2.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token    $'do\r''`

`mlimport-magento2.sh: line 7:     do`

```
#!/bin/bash
if exists *.ZIP
then
    # disable autoindexing
    #php -f "$MAGEPATH"shell/indexer.php -- --mode-manual all
    for file in `ls *.ZIP`
    do
        # Backup zip file
        cp $file /backups
        # Extract XML files
        unzip -P web $file
        # Delete zip file
        rm -f $file
        # rename xml files
        # hier komt procedure die controleert of bestand xxx*basic.xml bestaat en zo ja dan wordt dit bestand hernoemt en daarna geexecuteerd
        if [ -f "*basic.xml" ]
        then
            mv *_BASIC.XML BASIC.XML
            php -f bin/magento import:job:run 1
        fi
        # rename xml files
        # hier komt procedure die controleert of bestand xxx*prices.xml bestaat en zo ja dan wordt dit bestand hernoemt en daarna geexecuteerd
        if [ -f "*prices.xml" ]
        then
            mv *_PRICES.XML PRICES.XML
            php -f bin/magento import:job:run 4
            php -f bin/magento import:job:run 2
        fi
        # rename xml files
        # hier komt procedure die controleert of bestand xxx*stock.xml bestaat en zo ja dan wordt dit bestand hernoemt en daarna geexecuteerd
        if [ -f "*stockinfo.xml" ]
        then
            mv *_STOCKINFO.XML STOCKSTOCK.XML
            php -f bin/magento import:job:run 3
        fi
    done
    # verplaats .XML files naar backup
        cp -f $file ../backups
    # Delete XML files
        rm -f *.XML
fi
```

Comment: The script is probably in DOS/Windows format; see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings).

Comment: Your script is a DOS text file with DOS newlines (carriage-return+linefeed). Convert it with `dos2unix`. You additionally use `ls` needlessly when you could just loop safer over the expansion of a file glob (`for file in *.ZIP`). You have several other errors in your code which would make it fail to do what you want. I suggest rewriting it and testing each piece of code as you add it to the script. Also test what would happen with filenames containing spaces and globbing characters (`touch '* name.ZIP'`; with current code, having a file with this name causes data loss due to `rm -f $file`).

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, you can also check for syntax errors by pasting your code here: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `for file in $(ls *.ZIP)` - useless and error prone use of `ls`.

Comment: i change the script and rewrite it in vi editor and now it is working correct. However it is more easy if i can make script files also on my windows machine. Is there a editor for windows which writes script files in the correct format without the linefeeds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there's the obvious issue with CRLF newlines, the `\r` in the error message being a tell-tale sign. See e.g. [How to bulk convert all the file in a file system branch between Unix and Windows line break format?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22604/170373) on how to fix that.

Then, you have

```
if exists *.ZIP
then
```

which might also be DOS-ism, at least I've not heard of a utility called `exists`.

Also here:

```
for file in `ls *.ZIP`
```

is a useless use of `ls`. What happens is that the shell expands the filename pattern `*.ZIP`, passes the results to `ls`, which the... just prints the same names out. Except that you run into issues with word splitting of the result.

Instead of those two, use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in ./*.ZIP; do
    ...
done
```

First, the shell is quite capable of listing the matching filenames (it's what you did above with `exists *.ZIP`). Then, Bash's `nullglob` makes the pattern expand to nothing if there are no matching files. Otherwise you might get errors about a file literally called `*.ZIP` not existing. Prefixing the pattern with `./` makes some potential problems with filenames starting with dashes go away.

Also, you used unquoted expansions of `$file` all the way, i.e. `rm -f $file`, instead of `rm -f "$file"`. That, too, leads to issues with word splitting, see:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373)

Also,

```
if [ -f "*basic.xml" ]
```

this doesn't work, because the quotes prevent the pattern from being expanded to actual filenames. It would look for a file literally called `*basic.xml`. If you're sure there can only be one match, then `if [ -f *basic.xml ]` could do. If there are more, that would give an error because the test would get too many arguments.

Also, this will probably give an error, unless `BASIC.XML` is an existing directory.

```
mv *_BASIC.XML BASIC.XML
```

Okay, I think the suggestion to write the script in smaller parts, and test them individually (possibly with some debugging output sprinkled in), would be a good idea.